# arrange() doesn't recognize column name parameter

Tags: r, dplyr

Within R, I use `dplyr` and more specifically `arrange()`.
Somehow the `arrange` function doesn't work as expected.

In the example below first I store the name of a column, then I pass this variable as a parameter to a custom function called 'my_function'.

```
target_column = 'mean_age'

# below the function
my_function <- function(target_column, number){
    df <- read.csv('file.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    df <- df[, c(1,4,10)]
    names(df) <-  c('place','state','mean_age')
    df1 <- df %>% group_by(state) %>% arrange(target_column) 
    df1 %>% summarise(rank = nth(target_column, number))        
}
```

R returns an error when 'my_function' is called due to the input to `arrange()`:

> "Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 4000"

When the name of the column is put directly into `arrange()`, instead of a variable that references to a string (like example above), it does accept the parameter.

```
df %>% group_by(state) %>% arrange(mean_age)
```

How can I pass the parameter for the column name in a better way to 'my_function', so `arrange()` will recognize it?

Comment: In a simple case where you are using `arrange` in a function and want to pass a variable as a string, you can use `arrange_at` in place of `arrange`.  Your case looks more complicated to me, what with `nth` and `summarise`, so using unquoting/quosures for programming may make more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first parse your string argument to a quosure, then unquote it with `!!`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

target_column = 'mean_age'

my_function <- function(target_column, number){
    target_quo = parse_quosure(target_column)

    df <- read.csv('file.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    df <- df[, c(1,4,10)]
    names(df) <-  c('place','state','mean_age')
    df1 <- df %>% group_by(state) %>% arrange(!!target_quo) 
    df1 %>% summarise(rank = nth(target_column, number))        
}

my_function('mean_age', 10)
```

If you want to be able to supply `target_column` as an unquoted column name, you can use `enquo` instead:

```
my_function <- function(target_column, number){
    target_quo = enquo(target_column)

    df <- read.csv('file.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    df <- df[, c(1,4,10)]
    names(df) <-  c('place','state','mean_age')
    df1 <- df %>% group_by(state) %>% arrange(!!target_quo) 
    df1 %>% summarise(rank = nth(target_column, number))        
}

my_function(mean_age, 10)
```

**Note:**

Normally, `enquo` will also work for string arguments, but `arrange` itself does not allow it, so the following does not work for the second example:

```
my_function('mean_age', 10)
```

Below is a toy example to demonstrate what I mean, since OP's question is not reproducible:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

test_func = function(var){
    var_quo = parse_quosure(var)
    mtcars %>%
      select(!!var_quo) %>%
      arrange(!!var_quo)
}

test_func2 = function(var){
  var_quo = enquo(var)
  mtcars %>%
    select(!!var_quo) %>%
    arrange(!!var_quo)
}
```

**Results:**

```
> test_func("mpg") %>%
+   head()
   mpg
1 10.4
2 10.4
3 13.3
4 14.3
5 14.7
6 15.0

> test_func2(mpg) %>%
+   head()
   mpg
1 10.4
2 10.4
3 13.3
4 14.3
5 14.7
6 15.0

> test_func2("mpg") %>%
+   head()
```

> Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 32

Comment: or he can just use `arrange_` instead of `arrange`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper How can you make it to work for both `my_function('mean_age', 10)` and `my_function(mean_age, 10)` though? Besides, `arrange_` is deprecated

Comment: Thanks for the effort. That solved the problem for now. Order by which libraries are loaded made a difference as well.

Comment: For simple cases, `arrange_at` can work in functions with string inputs.

Answer (score 4):

An update is necessary to the good answer by @avid_useR because 'rlang::parse_quosure' is deprecated now.

To give a short answer to the question how to make 'dplyr::arrange' accept a string or variable containing a string for the column name to sort, you can do:

```
target_column = rlang::sym('mean_age')
df %>% group_by(state) %>% arrange(!!target_column)
```

OR as one-liner (if you only need to use it once):

```
df %>% group_by(state) %>% arrange(!!rlang::sym(target_column))
```

Answer (score 1):

*2022/03/17* The tidyverse has evolved and so should this answer. The tidy eval functions *equo/unquo, sym/ensym*, etc. are no longer the commended approach.

```r
library("tidyverse")

# Simulate data
read_df <- function(n = 100) {
  set.seed(1234)
  tibble(
    state = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), n, replace = TRUE),
    mean_age = rnorm(n)
  )
}
```

Case 1. If the target column is given as a string, use the .data pronoun, ie, `.data[[column_name]])`.

```r
my_function <- function(column_name, number) {
  read_df() %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    arrange(
      # Use `across(all_of())` instead of `across()` even with a single column
      # Otherwise will get the following warning:
      # > Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous
      across(all_of(column_name))
    ) %>%
    summarise(
      rank = nth(.data[[column_name]], number)
    )
}

my_function("mean_age", 10)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   state   rank
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 A     -0.420
#> 2 B     -0.584
#> 3 C     -0.141
```

Case 2. If the target column is given as a variable, there is no need for `enquo` anymore! Instead enclose [tidy-select](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) expressions in double braces `{{ }}`, aka *embrace* it.

```r
my_function <- function(column_var, number) {
  read_df() %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    arrange(
      {{ column_var }}
    ) %>%
    summarise(
      rank = nth({{ column_var }}, number)
    )
}

my_function(mean_age, 10)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   state   rank
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 A     -0.420
#> 2 B     -0.584
#> 3 C     -0.141
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This answer resolves the issue for me, @dipetkov, thank you. Curious to me is why `dplyr::select({{ var }}` works, but `arrange({{ var }})`, doesn’t (though your solution, with `.data[[{{ var}}]]` does work).

Comment: @rdelrossi Do you mean that `var` is a string which refers to a column name? For example, `var` = "column_a". Then `select(df, {{var}})` selects the column but `arrange(df, {{var}})` doesn't sort by the column? The difference is that `select` uses [tidy-selection](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) and `arrange` uses [data-masking](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/args_data_masking.html).

Comment: See more here: [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). From practical point of view, I sometimes have to try one way or the other to get it right.

Comment: Well said on both counts, @dipetkov. Appreciate your reply. This is likely a thread I’ll return to next time I face this.