# Replacing group_by_ with group_by when the argument is a string in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have some code that specifies a grouping variable as a string.

```
group_var <- "cyl"
```

My current code for using this grouping variable in a dplyr pipeline is:

```
mtcars %>% 
     group_by_(group_var) %>% 
     summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
```

My best guess as to how to replace the deprecated `group_by_` function with `group_by` is:

```
mtcars %>% 
     group_by(!!as.name(group_var)) %>% 
     summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
```

This works but is not explicitly mentioned in the [programming with dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html).

Is using `!!as.name()` the preferred way to replace `group_by_()` with `group_by()`?

Comment: Another option is `group_by_at` - `group_by_at(mtcars, group_var)`.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056091/arrange-doesnt-recognize-column-name-parameter/47056273#47056273

Comment: You can also use `library(rlang); group_by(!!parse_quosure(group_var))`

Comment: For context this is in a shiny app and the grouping variable is a user input contained in the variable `input$group_var`.

Comment: @useR Thanks. I think `parse_quosure()` is the function I'm after. `group_by_at` works but doesn't generalize to solving this problem with other tidyverse functions.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `parse_quosure()` over `as.name()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this within a function? Otherwise I think the `!!as.name()` part is unnecessary and I would stick with the `group_by_at(group_var)` suggestion by @aosmith for simplicity sake.  Otherwise, I would set it up as so:

```
examplr <- function(data, group_var){
  group_var <- as.name(group_var)

  data %>% 
    group_by(!!group_var) %>% 
    summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
}

examplr(data = mtcars,
        group_var = "cyl")
```

Comment: Any reason not to do this `group_by(!!as.name(group_var))`?

Comment: No reason immediately comes to mind, but since you asked for preferred method, I figured `group_by_at()` is simpler than `group_by(!!as.name())`.  But if you plan on using `group_var` multiple times in your `dplyr` pipeline, I would recommend using the function approach I outlined above.  That way, you will only need to call on your variable by `!!group_var` rather than `!!as.name(group_var)` each time.

Comment: You can actually use `group_by_at` in a function and pass the variable name as a string directly to it (no "unquoting" needed).

Comment: All this new quoting and unquoting stuff is making my head spin. New to me anyway.