# How can you make tidyverse functions that support both quoted and unquoted arguments?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I know how to make functions that support quasi-quotation for an argument named 'variable' {using `dplyr::enquo(variable)` for unquoted function arguments} or functions that require you to quote the argument {using `rlang::sym("variable")`}. Is there an easy way to make functions that support both quoted an unquoted arguments?

For instance, `dplyr::select()` allows both `select(mtcars, mpg)` and `select(mtcars, "mpg")`. What is the best practice for building a function that can do either? One consideration is the impact on data masking, which I'm unsure if I need to consider in building out more complex functions.

I've been looking through the github pages for the basic dplyr functions, but a simple function like select relies on a whole new package (tidyselect), so there is a lot going on. I didn't see a clear explanation in the Tidy evaluation book either. Below is a hack function that supports both quoted and unquoted arguments, but this is not a reliable solution. I'm sure there is an easier way.

```
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)

test_func <- function(variable) {
  if(nrow(count(mtcars, {{variable}})) == 1) {
    variable <- rlang::sym(variable)
  }
  count(mtcars, {{variable}})
}

all_equal(
  test_func(cyl),
  test_func("cyl")
)
```

Comment: There is no useful purpose for this kind of UI because you can't save the string in a variable and refer to it the normal way. If you really want to do this, use `ensym()` as suggested by akrun, it implements the same semantics as on the LHS of `=` or in the `library()` function.

Comment: I admit it's not a huge gain to support both types, and I am interested in the downsides of this approach. What cases would ```ensym()``` fail in? Could you not convert the symbol back to a character string if you needed to store it as a variable (say for labelling in a ggplot)?

Comment: The downside is that if someone sees `foo("bar")`, they might try `quux <- "bar"; foo(quux)` and they will be confused that it doesn't work in the same way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it needs to work on both quoted/unquoted, use `ensym`

```
test_func <- function(variable) {  

    dplyr::count(mtcars, !!rlang::ensym(variable))    

  }
```

-testing

```
test_func(cyl)
#  cyl  n
#1   4 11
#2   6  7
#3   8 14
test_func('cyl')
#  cyl  n
#1   4 11
#2   6  7
#3   8 14
```

NOTE: Better to have data also as an argument to the function

Comment: Thanks! Are there major downsides to this approach, in comparison to requiring an argument be either quoted or unquoted? I ask because ```ensym()``` is discussed a lot less in tidy eval sources in comparison to ```enquo()```, even though at first glance ```ensym()``` is more versatile.

Comment: @bholly I think enquo is mostly speciified because many people want to pass unquoted strings  as argument compared to quoted.  With quoted, there are many optioins. i.e. you can use `[[` or `[` to subset the column in `base R`, while unquoted requires substitute/deparse.

Comment: @bholly also, f this is n production setting, it is better to have a confluence page where you specify the arguments passed, along with its expectations so that the user  won't pass quoted and unquoted

Comment: I was planning on including expectations for arguments within the function documentation (the functions I'm working on are within a package on a private repo). Something similar to the tidy-eval comments for the ```...``` argument in ```dplyr::filter()```.

Comment: @akrun For the same example, why does it not work if I do,

value <- "cyl"

test_func(value)

Comment: @ArunKumaar you need to escape `test_func(!!value)` to evaluate the contents in value or else it thinks that you are passing literal `value`